# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null but Have set ID

Tags: jquery, image, src

I've got this script that adds a ID to a img tag and then a function that changes the image src with a different colored version as seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$('.custom-logo-link img').each(function(i) {
$(this).attr('id', 'img-logo' + i);
});
});

function setImg(){
var numRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
document.getElementById("img-logo0").src = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Logo"+numRand+".jpg";}

setImg();

window.setInterval("setImg()",1000);
</script>
```

My issue is that I keep on getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null but I have set the ID it should look at.

Comment: can you provide a working js/html example of your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `setImg()` inside the document ready, then you won't have the issue of the ID not being set yet and getElementById failing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.custom-logo-link img').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'img-logo' + i);
    });

// Move this to the end: });

    function setImg(){
        var numRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        document.getElementById("img-logo0").src = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Logo"+numRand+".jpg";
    }
    setImg();
    window.setInterval(setImg, 1000);
});
```